# Using Varnish Cache while preserving Google Analytics cookie on a NGINX SSL Terminator

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, google-analytics, varnish

I am using the Unixy Varnish plugin for cPanel and one particular website and all its subdomains use Full SSL + HTTP Strict Transport Security.

Nginx listens on a non-standard ssl port, passes the request to Varnish which by default strips all cookies. The request is then finally served up by Apache.

The website is mostly static html, with a WordPress subdomain, IPB installation, Piwik installation additionally.

The main domain is only static pages so I would like to force Varnish to cache it anyway since there isn't anything that involves logging in, then strip cookies excluding those belonging to Google Analytics.

Currently for Google Analytics I am using the script from http://www.ga-script.org, which uses the classical tracking code js. I intend to add the Universal Analytics code in addition, removing my UA-XXXXXXX id (Only from the classical js).

Then I will parse the Analytics cookie (as described here: http://www.dannytalk.com/read-google-analytics-cookie-script/), with the fix for Universal Analytics, in the latest comment on that post - so I can pass the resulting values to Piwik and/or a CRM system.

I'm not 100% clear on what I need to do to configure Varnish correctly for this kind of scenario and would appreciate others help with this.

**Current Varnish config supplied by Unixy:**

```
###################################################
# Copyright (c) UNIXY  -  http://www.unixy.net    #
# The leading truly fully managed server provider #
###################################################

include "/etc/varnish/cpanel.backend.vcl";

include "/etc/varnish/backends.vcl";

# mod_security rules
include "/etc/varnish/security.vcl";

sub vcl_recv {

# Use the default backend for all other requests
set req.backend = default;

# Setup the different backends logic
include "/etc/varnish/acllogic.vcl";

# Allow a grace period for offering "stale" data in case backend lags
set req.grace = 5m;

remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

# cPanel URLs
include "/etc/varnish/cpanel.url.vcl";

# Properly handle different encoding types
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|ico)$") {
        # No point in compressing these
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
        # unkown algorithm
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}

# Set up disabled
include "/etc/varnish/disabled.vcl";

# Exclude upgrade, install, server-status, etc
include "/etc/varnish/known.exclude.vcl";

# Set up exceptions
include "/etc/varnish/url.exclude.vcl";

# Set up exceptions
include "/etc/varnish/debugurl.exclude.vcl";

# Set up exceptions
include "/etc/varnish/vhost.exclude.vcl";

# Set up vhost+url exceptions
include "/etc/varnish/vhosturl.exclude.vcl";

# Set up cPanel reseller exceptions
include "/etc/varnish/reseller.exclude.vcl";

# Restart rule for bfile recv
include "/etc/varnish/bigfile.recv.vcl";


if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ acl127_0_0_1) {error 405 "Not permitted";}
        return (lookup);
}

## Default request checks
if (req.request != "GET" &&
req.request != "HEAD" &&
req.request != "PUT" &&
req.request != "POST" &&
req.request != "TRACE" &&
req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
req.request != "DELETE") {
    return (pipe);
}

if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
}

## Modified from default to allow caching if cookies are set, but not http auth
if (req.http.Authorization) {
    return (pass);
}

include "/etc/varnish/versioning.static.vcl";

## Remove has_js and Google Analytics cookies.
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(__[a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");

set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

include "/etc/varnish/slashdot.recv.vcl";

# Cache things with these extensions
if (req.url ~ "\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|pdf)$" && ! (req.url ~ "\.(php)") ) {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (lookup);
}

return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_fetch {

set beresp.ttl = 40s;
set beresp.http.Server = " - Web acceleration by http://www.unixy.net/varnish ";

# Turn off Varnish gzip processing
include "/etc/varnish/gzip.off.vcl";

# Grace to allow varnish to serve content if backend is lagged
set beresp.grace = 5m;

# Restart rule bfile for fetch
include "/etc/varnish/bigfile.fetch.vcl";

# These status codes should always pass through and never cache.
if (beresp.status == 503 || beresp.status == 500) {
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO: beresp.status";
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable-status = beresp.status;
    return (hit_for_pass);
}

if (beresp.status == 404) {
    set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
    set beresp.ttl = 20s;
    return (deliver);
}

/* Remove Expires from backend, it's not long enough */    
unset beresp.http.expires;

if (req.url ~ "\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|pdf|ico)$" && ! (req.url ~ "\.(php)") ) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    include "/etc/varnish/static.ttl.vcl";
}
include "/etc/varnish/slashdot.fetch.vcl"; 
else {
    include "/etc/varnish/dynamic.ttl.vcl";
}

/* marker for vcl_deliver to reset Age: */
set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";

# All tests passed, therefore item is cacheable
set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";

return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {

  # From http://varnish-cache.org/wiki/VCLExampleLongerCaching
  if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
     /* Remove the magic marker */
     unset resp.http.magicmarker;

     /* By definition we have a fresh object */
     set resp.http.age = "0";
   }
   set resp.http.Location = regsub(resp.http.Location, ":[0-9]+", "");

   #add cache hit data
   if (obj.hits > 0) {
     #if hit add hit count
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
     set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
   }
else {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
   }

}

sub vcl_error {

if (obj.status == 503 && req.restarts < 5) {
set obj.http.X-Restarts = req.restarts;
return (restart);
}

}

# Added to let users force refresh
sub vcl_hit {

if (obj.ttl < 1s) {
    return (pass);
}

if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
# Ignore requests via proxy caches,  IE users and badly behaved crawlers
# like msnbot that send no-cache with every request.
if (! (req.http.Via || req.http.User-Agent ~ "bot|MSIE|HostTracker")) {
    set obj.ttl = 0s;
    return (restart);
} 
}

return (deliver);

}

sub vcl_hash {

    hash_data(req.http.cookie);
}
```

Comment: If I understood your scenario correctly, you don't need to keep Google Analytics cookies in the request since the GA cookie is processed using JavaScript on the client browser. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the GA cookie from the request, their are not used by your backend.

You can for example remove all cookie except for admin

```
if ( !( req.url ~ ^/admin/) ) {
  unset req.http.Cookie;
}
```

Or discard all cookies that start with a underscore:

```
// Remove has_js and Google Analytics __* cookies.
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
// Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
```

https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/increasing-your-hitrate.html